# Delete photos older than x days in iOS

Tags: iphone, photos

In order to free up storage on my iPhone, I want to delete some of my older photos. Instead of deleting each one manually, is there a way to delete photos older than x days, or even delete all the photos from 2017?

Comment: Are the photos only stored locally on the phone, or also in iCloud (through iCloud Photos)?

Comment: Yes - be very sure you have backups and know if your photo library is being synced - a delete from iOS will delete out of the cloud if you choose the default iCloud photos options when you sign in to iCloud and sync any photos via your AppleID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - if you don't need to make backups or transfer, install the Shortcuts app (used to be called Workflow) before Apple bought the company and renamed / shipped / enhanced the automation app for iOS.

You need two items - Find Photos and Delete Photos

For Find Photos, you can choose photos before a date. If you're not sure, you can limit it to 5 photos so you can validate it's getting the ones you want to delete.

Just be sure you know if your iCloud photo library is tied to the iPhone since deleting a photo will then cascade and delete in the cloud as well.

- [Delete photos on iPad without affecting photos on iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249980/delete-photos-on-ipad-without-affecting-photos-on-iphone)
- [Deleting photos off of my iPhone but leave photos in the cloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205461/deleting-photos-off-of-my-iphone-but-leave-photos-in-the-cloud)

Comment: Got the shortcut app and added Select Photos (turned on multiple) and Delete Photos.  But when I exercise the shortcut I get no option to select by date.

Comment: Same - I also get no option to select by date. I'm on iOS 14.8.

Comment: Use a Find Photos block which has filters (not Select Photos).

Comment: Thanks so much @mfink for the improvements here

Answer (score 1):

After spending a few painful hours researching this, I have found the best way is to use the "Transfer" app.  In iTunes "Simple Transfer - Photo+Video" by Rambax.  It's a paid app, so stop reading if not interested, but I think it's well worth it. I'm not in any way affiliated with them, and did not get anything for this post, and would rather have a free way of doing it, but just could not find a way.

Transfer app has two main features:

- Helps transfer your images between devices or your laptop
- Has a "Cleaner" to delete ("Organize") photos by date range

So Just open the app, select Cleaner from the bottom toolbar, Organize Photos, press Select... on the top right and select "Date Range".  The Start and End Dates will be preset to your oldest and newest photos.  Change as desired and press "SELECT".  Now you can press "Delete" at the bottom left.

Works Fantastic!

After deleting in the Transfer app, you have 30 days to recover them from your "Recently Deleted" list.  But if you are in this to save space on your phone like me, you can go to Photos, scroll all the way to the bottom to the "Recently Delete" album, press Select at the top, and press Delete All at the bottom.

Life savor when you need some space, but you don't want to delete all photos, just older than (that you know you've already synced).

I also use Transfer to transfer photos too.  On windows the standard transfer methods all suck and constantly get stuck when transferring large photos and videos.  This app is the only way I know that consistently works and you can do it on Wifi without any cables and even between different iPhones.

Comment: FYI future readers: the app is $12 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through some of the options found on Google, none of the seemed simple or cheap enough, so I decided on the most native and local option.

I went to iOs (15.6) Images and found out almost accidentally, that I can do a **date** search by an iso **tag-method** of sorts. I can write the year (2021) and it chooses the year, then I can add the month (January).

Now I have at least one month or year at my hands, and I can delete a selected time frame by selecting the filtered images.
(But please Apple, have a **select all** in the app, now I learned the scrolling select to work allright for now though..)